# Prestashop 1.6.1.4 - Undefined constant for custom module

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

We have upgraded from Prestashop 1.6.0.9 to 1.6.1.4. After updating to new version one of our custom module started throwing Fatal Error like :

[PHP ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lX0u.png)

We have defined this constant in the classes/pdf/PDF.php file.

I am not able to trace the error as it was working previously. Any help or reference will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define this constant in your custom module like that:

```
if (!defined('TEMPLATE_PRODUCT_RETURN'))
{
    define('TEMPLATE_PRODUCT_RETURN', '...');
}
```